# Responsive email layout

Tags: html-email, responsive-design

I am trying to build a responsive email template but have run into some trouble, as it's table  based I am wondering how I can achieve this http://d.pr/BUKq

Basically it kind of works now with the layout I have as I hide box B when in web view, and show it in the mobile view (while I hide box a) both boxes have the same content. Tho I run ino trouble when adding another side bar box. I'd like to have it modular without creating 2 of each box, I can show code if that helps any more.

Comment: Good luck with that! Even the major internet companies do not do that in their emails

Comment: Hey Sam,

If you mean make emails responsive, I have seen a few, Campaign Monitor also offers some templates I think, it's just I have a few extra requirements but having trouble implementing them.

Comment: Solved, just used tables everywhere :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tables everywhere and give inline css